# How to disable click when highlighting text

Tags: javascript, events, copy-paste, highlight

I have a use case where I have a table with clickable row elements. Each row has some text which I want to allow users to copy. When I am trying to highlight the text, I want to prevent the `click` event.

```js
document.querySelector('tr').onclick = function () {
  window.alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
table {
 border: 1px solid;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td> This row is clickable </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>Try to highlight the text above by moving your cursor. I want to prevent click when you are trying to highlight the text which means you should not get the alert dialog.</div>
```

Comment: please post your relevant code here

Comment: You can check if the user [has selected any text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) in your click event handler. Alternatively you can attach another event listener and call [stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) if the user has selected any text.

Comment: I believe now my question is crystal clear. If you still need more explanation please let me know before downvoting it again.

Answer (score -1):

I think that doesnot really work like that.. its mostly used to disable radio,checkbox and others... here are some codes

Code 1:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Try to check this box: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">

<p>Toggling a checkbox is the default action of clicking on a checkbox. The 
preventDefault() method prevents this from happening.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myCheckbox").addEventListener("click", 
function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code 2:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <body>

      <a id="myAnchor" href="https://w3schools.com/">Go to W3Schools.com</a>

      <p>The preventDefault() method will prevent the link above from following the URL.</p>

      <script>
      document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
      });
      </script>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: what has this to do with the OPs question?

Comment: This is not what I am looking for actually. I have updated my question now.